# How to convert the difference between dates in any human format using Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, time

Sorry for the title of the question! I really tried, but I don't even know how to explain my problem in right programatic terms. So it *might be duplicate* (if so - i'm sorry for that). Please, be so kind to *edit my question* or just *make a suggestion in comments*!

**Situation:**

```
time_passed = Time.now - Post.find(id).created_at
```

It gives something like: `3601688.541388227` and it is "Float"

How to make this look like something time-like which a human can understand), because now when I use `Time.at(time_passed)` it gives a predictable rubbish.

Comment: what do you want to receive? Could you give us examples of the output you need?

Comment: Some thing like: x hour y minutes or just xxx minutes

Comment: _"It gives something like 3601688.541388227"_ – that's the **difference in seconds**. 3,601,688 seconds ≈ 60,028 minutes ≈ 1,000 hours ≈ 41 days. And no, it doesn't make much sense to feed that number into [`Time.at`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Time.html#method-c-at).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you talking about ago timestamp like a facebook?
like: 
day ago
1 min ago
week ago
3 months ago
year ago
please follow this document: 
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html
http://stevenyue.com/blogs/date-time-datetime-in-ruby-and-rails/